# Form 1 Does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Guys i am making a media player in c# and when I click a button there is a code which redirect form 1 to form 2, That code worked on the first 4 forms (I mean form1,form2,form3...) and then i added form 5 but in form 5 when I type the redirect code I am getting this error "Form 1 Does not exist in the current context" This is my Designer.cs

```
namespace MineMusic
{
    partial class Form5
    {
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // Form5
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(830, 470);
        this.Name = "Form5";
        this.Text = "Form5";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form5_Load);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion
}
```

}

And this is my code for redirect

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            this.Hide();
            f2.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: The partial class is named Shortcut1 while  in InitializeComponent the Designer works with Shortcut. This might be your problem.

Can you show us also the "redirect" code ?

Comment: Maybe you're renaming your form directly rather than using right-click>refactor ?

Comment: I just put a wrong code.

Comment: You provided the class **Form5** and the code that creates **Form2** instance, but got the error "**Form 1** Does not..."?